# Python / Pip - Sharing modules between projects without setup.py

Tags: python, pip

I have two private Python projects, Project1 and Project2. Project1 needs to use models and scripts defined in Project2.

I was hoping it would be as easy as adding:

```
git+git@bitbucket/user/Project2.git
```

To my requirements.txt, but I am getting errors that there is a missing setup.py since the Project2 doesn't use setuptools.

What is the simplest way of using Project2 within Project1? Do I have to create the module using a setup.py or is there a simpler way?

Using symlinks etc isn't an option because I'll beed to eventually deploy this to a server and retain the dependancy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, make it standard package with setup.py. Other methods exists, but are mostly more complicated.